# How to get the value on load in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**This function in jquery**

```
var someval = $('#someid').html();
if(someval !=""){
//something
}else{
//anything
}
```

How to write the same function in angularjs ?? I am a beginner in angular js. How to solve this ?? 
Can anyone provide me some example for this one ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var someval = angular.element('#someid').html();
if(someval !=""){
  //something
}else{
  //anything
}
```

I hope It Helps !

Comment: how to write the  $('#someid').hide(); in angular js ??

Comment: in this case you need to use ng-hide=""! 
HTML:
ng-show="hideNow"
CONTROLLER:
$scope.hideNow = true; //put false for show

Check that
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in angular:

```
var someval = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#someid' ) ).html();
if(someval !=""){
  //something
}else{
  //anything
}
```